# Retrieving the documents connected this vertex

Tags: arangodb, aql

I would like to retrieve all documents connected to the vertex.

First all my idea was to find a vertex by using the information stored in it. I was able to do it with a full text query:

```
FOR doc IN spec
FILTER doc.serial_no == '"12345abc"'
RETURN doc

RESULT:
[
  {
    "_key": "3834670", 
    "_id": "spec/3834670", 
    "_rev": "_WP3-fvW---",
    "type": "spec-type-545",
    "name": "spec-name-957", 
    "serial_no": ""12345abc""
  }
]
```

Now I would like to find all documents attached to this vertex. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you save connections from your vertex to its attached documents in edge collections you can use a traversal.

A traversal starts at one specific document (startVertex) and follows all edges connected to this document. For all documents (vertices) that are targeted by these edges it will again follow all edges connected to them and so on.

In your case the startVertex is `'spec/3834670'`. `IN [min[..max]]` defines the depth of the traversal, not specifying this option will use the default depth of 1. `edgeCollection1, ..., edgeCollectionN` is a list of all edge collections in use.

```
FOR v IN [min[..max]] ANY 'spec/3834670'
  edgeCollection1, ..., edgeCollectionN
  RETURN v._key
```

This is documented in the [AQL Manual](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.2/AQL/Graphs/Traversals.html).

Comment: You can achieve this in one query by nesting the for loops:

`FOR doc IN spec
  FILTER doc.serial_no == '"12345abc"'
  FOR v IN [min[..max]] ANY doc._id
    edgeCollection1, ..., edgeCollectionN
    RETURN v._key`

In case multiple elements would pass the first filter, the traversal would run for each of the found vertices.